# Declare one Ajax Function and fill it with different variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make my page more efficient by using a separated ".js" file and trying to declare multilple used functions only one time. So I have to declare them in a way, that they caa be used for different situations. For Example passing different data.

Here is my Ajax Function in the "functions.js" file:

```
function CallAjax(type, url, data, div){

$.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(div).html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my Code in my PHP File where I use this function and pass Parameters:

```
CallAjax('POST', 'about.php', '{ aufid : id }', '#con2');
```

My Problem is the "data" section. How can I declare it? The way I'm doing it doesn't work.

I don't want to use a new Ajax Function everytime when I need different data... I'm trying to trigger less functions as possible.

If you have any tips to make the page more efficient by trying to use less code, then it would be awesome if you mention them, too! Thank you!

Comment: you passing a string, but object expected

Answer (score 3):

you can do it like this:

```
var obj = {
aufid: 1
};

CallAjax('POST', 'about.php', obj, '#con2');
```

Comment: What's the best way to make it in a OOP way? So I can creat new Objects but use the same AjaxCall function? Any good sources to better understand that?

Answer (score 1):

I propose js callback:

```
function CallAjax(type, url, data, div){
  $.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        callback(data);
    }
  });
}

var obj = {
    id:1
};

CallAjax('POST', 'about.php', obj, function(response){
    $(div).html(response);  //or other
});
```

or a more elegant way in [promise](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
function CallAjax(type, url, data){
  return $.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: data,
  });
}

var obj = { id: 1 };
var jxhr = CallAjax('POST', 'about.php', obj);

jxhr.done(function(response){
    //successful callback goes here...
}).fail(function(response){
    //failure callback goes here...
}).always(function(response){
    //always callback goes here...
});
```

: )